# Making a pointer const C++

Tags: c++, pointers, constants

I have two vectors of node pointers.

```
vector<Node*> tmp; 

vector<Node*> nodes;
```

and I say `tmp = nodes;`

If I `delete nodes`, then `tmp` is also deleted.

Is there any way to make `tmp` not be modified whenever `nodes` is modified, like making it const?

I'm basically running Dijkstra's. But this algorithm always deleted nodes vector in determining shortest path. Which means I can only do shortest path from a source to destination only once.

if I have a graph 0--->1--->2--->3
i.e

```
CGraph g;

g.Dijkstras(0);
g.PrintShortestRouteTo(2);
g.Dijktras(2);         
g.PrintShortestRouteTo(3);    <-- source is still 0 since nodes is deleted
                                  therefore I get the path from 0 to 2


  class Node
{
public:
    Node(int id)
        : id(id), previous(NULL),
        distanceFromStart(INT_MAX)
    {
        nodes.push_back(this);
    }
public:
    int id;
    Node* previous;
    int distanceFromStart;
};

vector<Node*> nodes;

void CGraph::Dijkstras(int source)
{

    nodes[source]->distanceFromStart =  0;   


    for (int i = 0; i < (int)nodes.size(); i++)
        cout << nodes[i]->distanceFromStart << " " ;

    cout << "------------------------" << endl;

    while (nodes.size() > 0)
    {
        Node* smallest = ExtractSmallest(nodes);
        //cout << "Smallest: " << smallest->id << " ";
        //Node* smallest = nnodes[1];
        vector<Node*>* adjacentNodes =
            AdjacentRemainingNodes(smallest);
        const int size = adjacentNodes->size();
        for (int i=0; i<size; ++i)
        {
            Node* adjacent = adjacentNodes->at(i);
            int distance = Distance(smallest, adjacent) +
                smallest->distanceFromStart;
            if (distance < adjacent->distanceFromStart)
            {
                adjacent->distanceFromStart = distance;
                adjacent->previous = smallest;
            }
        }
        delete adjacentNodes;
    }
}
```

Comment: `delete nodes` won't compile, `nodes` is not a pointer.

Comment: Did you mean `vector<Node>* tmp` ?

Comment: Yes, nodes is a pointer. I fixed it

Comment: @CyberShot: You did not.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot write `delete nodes`, as `nodes` is not a pointer. If you write that, the code would not compile.

When you write this:

```
vector<Node*> tmp = nodes;
```

then you make a copy of the vector object, not the contents of the vector. The contents of the vector is same in both copies of the vector. So if you change contents from one vector, the change will reflect in the other copy of the vector as well.

If you want to make copy of the contents also, then write this:

```
std::vector<Node*> tmp;
tmp.reserve(nodes.size()):

//include <algorithm> for std::transform
std::transform(nodes.begin(),   
               nodes.end(),
               std::back_inserter(tmp),
               [](Node const *node) { return new Node(*node); });
```

<sub>**Note:** the above code will compile in C++11 only, as it uses lambda expression. In C++03, you can use function or functor in its place.</sub>

Consider using smart pointers such as `std::unique_ptr<Node>` or `std::shared_ptr<Node>` in place of `Node*`. Smart pointers manage the memory itself, and you would need to worry about it. However, if you use smart pointers, then the above code will be little different, but the basic idea is same if you want to make copy of the contents.

Comment: Are you sure about the syntax? I get expected primary-expression before '[' and before ']' and before 'const' errors.

Comment: @CyberShot: ***Note:** the above code will compile in C++11 only, as it uses lambda expression. In C++03, you can use function or functor in its place.*

Comment: function or functor in place of what, exactly?

Comment: @CyberShot: Obviously, in place of Lambda.

Comment: I'm really lost. I don't know much about Lambda functions. What would the code look like to copy memory contents in older C++ compilers?

Comment: @CyberShot: Lambda comes with C++11. You need function (or functor) in place of lambda. So replace the lambda with function (or functor). Search how to use `std::transform`. Do some work yourself first. If you fail, then ask questions.

Answer (score 0):

One way to manage this is to use shared pointers instead

```
vector<shared_ptr<Node> > tmp;
```

that way even if tmp/Nodes goes out of scope before the other the objects (what Node* points to) still exist.

Answer (score 0):

You would likely need to implement a copy constructor for Node if it's a class, then loop through "nodes" to copy each item into tmp for that

```
tmp.clear();

for(vector<Node*>::iterator it = nodes.begin(); it != nodes.end(); it++)
{
    Node* copy = new Node((*it));

    tmp.push_back(copy);
}
```

Comment: I tried this but get a invalid conversion from Node* to int for some reason. I don't even see int in here though

Comment: I tried this and after I ran the program, tmp was still modified after I deleted nodes. This means that tmp and nodes are still linked together, but I want them to be independent!

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little confusing, but my interpretation is:

```
std::vector<Node *> *tmp;
std::vector<Node *> *nodes;

nodes = somehow_gets_dynamically_created_vector();
tmp = nodes;
// perhaps do other things with nodes
delete nodes;
```

Then, the code leaves `tmp` dangling (ie, it is pointing to freed memory). But. this should be safe:

```
std::vector<Node *> tmp;
std::vector<Node *> *nodes;

nodes = somehow_gets_dynamically_created_vector();
tmp = *nodes;
// perhaps do other things with nodes
delete nodes;
```

Now, in your sample code, the only code that looks vaguely similar to what you describe is how the code treats the `adjacentNodes` variable. And, I gather something bad happens to `nodes` as a result of the `delete adjacentNodes` line. I would make sure that the `AdjacentRemainingNodes` function is doing what you think it is supposed to do. At the very least it should be returning the value provided by a call to `new std::vector<Node *>` somewhere within the code executed within the body of that function. If it does not, the `delete` on `adjacentNodes` is invalid.

But perhaps you had a different meaning in mind. If instead you mean that after copying `nodes` to `tmp`, that `tmp` sees the updated values to `distantFromStart`, then this is a consequence of using pointers. You can avoid that problem by not using pointers in your vector.

```
std::vector<Node> tmp;
std::vector<Node> nodes;

tmp = nodes;
```

However, you will need to define a copy constructor or otherwise figure out how to deal with the `previous` member. For example, the copy constructor could just set the `previous` member to `NULL` rather than copy the value from the LHS.

```
Node::Node (const Node &lhs)
    : id(lhs.id), previous(NULL), distanceFromStart(lhs.distanceFromStart)
 {}
```

But you should do what ever is appropriate.